# how to check password contain username on word or special characters in PHP

Tags: php

i have username and password, i need to check if password are specific on username or not

My Code is

```
$username = "paul.gilbert";
$password = "Paul@2019";
if (stripos($password,$username) !== false) {
    echo "password contains username";
}else{
    echo "good password";
}
```

how to check if i have username and password like this?

Comment: my result always "good password" but it's contain their username

Comment: The password above does not contain the username, only part of it, that's why it shows "good password"

Comment: @catcon nah i need to get its part of username or not

Comment: When your say "part", how many percent is considered "a part"? for example, does "aul" consider part? How about "er"?

Comment: as documentation of stripos is saying that it checks the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string, So password doesn't contain the username. if all usernames should contain a dot, then you can explode your username by dot, then check each part of the user name separately. of course, make sure you make both username parts and password strtolower before check.

Comment: maybe divided by "." such as "Paul" or "paul" or "gilBert or etc

Comment: @HamedGhasempour thank you for your explanation, all of username should contain a dot. i will try your explanation, thanks

Comment: Then you can use `explode()` to split the username into an array, loop through that array then use `stripos()` to check if the password contain the string.

Comment: @catcon yeah i will try, thank you

Comment: how is considered by part? i want 3 words like "pau" or "aul"

Comment: _"i want 3 words like "pau" or "aul""_ - That's two words. Do you mean three characters? You should also be careful. if it can't even contain three of the characters in a row, people with long names will be much more restricted when choosing a password, which doesn't seem fair...

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/***************************************
Change the special character with blank.
explode username by blank
$username [0] - First name
$username [1] - Last name

Make it  case insensitive use  strtolower function
*****************************************/

$username = explode(' ', (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+/', ' ', 'paul.gilbert')));

$Firstname = strtolower($username[0]);
$lastname = strtolower($username[1]);

$password = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+/', ' ', 'Paul@2019'));


//check if password contains first name or last name of username 
if (stripos($password,$Firstname) !== false || stripos($password,$lastname) !== false) {
    echo "password contains username";
}else{
    //If not contains make it good password
    echo "good password";
}

?>
```

Solution 2- if you want 3 words like "pau" or "aul". Use preg_match

```
//check if password contains first name or last name of username 
if(preg_match("/\b{$Firstname}\b/i", $password) || preg_match("/\b{$lastname}\b/i", $password)) {
    echo "password contains username";
}else{
    //If not contains make it good password
    echo "good password";
}
```